# What property identifies the monoid of positive integers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, monoid

What abstract algebraic properties uniquely identify the multiplicative monoid of positive integers among all free abelian monoids with infinitely many generators?

i.e. finish the sentence

> The positive integers with multiplication are the unique monoid ...

without a circular dependence on the monoid's own properties (such as its prime numbers).

Every multiplicative monoid generated by infinitely many primes is isomorphic. And clearly the positive integers form the unique monoid generated multiplicatively by the prime numbers, but the concept of "the prime numbers" is itself derived from the properties of the monoid.

I'm sure there must be an answer to this question that derives the properties of the additive monoid from the multiplicative one in such a way as to uniquely identify it as the positive integers.  If I was to take a stab at it, presumably it's something like:

The positive integers are the unique monoid whose set in union with an absorbing element, is also a monoid by a secondary binary function, over which the first function commutes, when the absorbing element is assumed the identity of the second function.

Comment: If you remove $0$, they're the free commutative monoid on countably many generators (btw since a free commutative monoid has exactly one set of free generators, this recovers primes for free). Therefore, with $0$ they're "the free commutative monoid on countably many generators + an absorbing element"

Comment: @Max: Since $0$ is not positive, there's no need to remove it. It's not in the set to begin with.

Comment: @celtschk : sorry I was thinking of positive in french (which means nonnegative) + OP mentioned the absorbing element (but after re-reading they said 'in union with an absorbing element' so I was mistaken)

Comment: @Max would you agree that your definition is insufficient to uniquely identify the positive integers as it would equally identify the odd, positive integers?

Comment: Yes, but they are isomorphic as monoids, so that any characterization of monoids you find for the positive integers would work for the odd positive integers

Comment: @Max I'm pointing that out to indicate I'm taking it as a premise of the question and which hopefully clarifies indicates what more I'm asking for in an answer.

Comment: I fear the answer might not be concise. If you'll allow a slight rewording for brevity later, I'd try something like: "The positive integers with multiplication are the minimal commutative monoid $M$ for which the minimum infinite-order Abelian group $G$ of identity $0$ under an additive operator, over which multiplication distributes, satisfies $x\in M\iff -x\notin M$ (where $-x$ denotes the $G$-inverse of $x$) for each $x\in G\setminus\{0\}$."

Comment: thank-you @J.G. What does minimal mean in ths context?

Comment: @samerivertwice That other options are supermonoids thereof.

Comment: If "unique" meant "up to isomorphism", the question was answered in the first comment. It should be clarified what stronger sense of "unique" you want. You seem to be changing the question to the positive numbers not just as a monoid, but as a more complex structure. Fine, but note that even then the strongest reasonable sense of "unique (such structure)" will be something like "unique up to unique isomorphism", as attempted in the only answer so far.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I totally agree. I edited to make it clear I'm starting with the isomorphism as a monoid as a given then asking what more uniquely identifies the natural numbers among those monoids. There's clearly some further condition on its generators. Any monoid isomorphic as a monoid can be given a 2nd function on which its set is another monoid, but only the natural numbers will have the same interrelation between its two functions. We might say it's the positive elements of a discrete ordered ring that is not a field, maybe that's the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Note $\mathfrak{C}$ the *[category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory)*

- whose objects are sets $R$ endowed with two binary laws $+$ and $\times$ such that $(R, +)$ is a commutative monoid and such that $(R,\times)$ has a neutral $1$ such that $1 \times r = r \times 1 = r$ for $r\in R$ and $n \times  1_R = \sum_{i=1}^n 1_R$ for all $n\in\mathbf{N}_0$.
- whose arrows (morphisms) are commutative monoid morphisms $\varphi : R' \to R$ such that $\varphi(1)=1$ and $\varphi(r_1 + r_2) = \varphi (r_1) + \varphi (r_2)$ and $\varphi(r_1 \times r_2) = \varphi (r_1) \times \varphi (r_2)$ for $r_1, r_2 \in R'$

Then the $(\mathbf{N_0}, 1, +, \times)$ (with the obvious $1$, $+$ and $\times$) is an *[initial object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_and_terminal_objects)* of $\mathfrak{C}$, meaning by that that it is a object of $\mathfrak{C}$ such that for each object $R$ in $\mathfrak{C}$, there is a unique morphism (in $\mathfrak{C}$) from $\mathbf{N}_0$ to $R$

Take such a morphism $\varphi$. Then if $p$ is a prime number $\varphi (p) = p \varphi(1) = p 1_R$. Thus $\varphi$ is unique, as any positive integer is product of prime numbers.

Comment: Thank-you. I interpret this to mean there's no automorphism from it to itself other than the identity automorphism, which is kinda like saying the primes are well-ordered.

Comment: Any such morphism is indeed determined uniquely by its values on prime numbers.

Comment: I edited my answer as apparently and old version of it was online.

Comment: I no longer think this answers the question as I intended it as I'm taking any multiplicative monoid generated by infinitely many primes being isomorphic, as a premise of the question and asking about the algebraic relation to addition, that enables us to then recover the additive monoid from it.

Comment: Ah yes ok, I reverted then. But if you think that my initial answer validates your question, validate the answer.

Comment: it does, but I'm not qualified to judge its correctness so I was just awaiting comments and votes from others better placed than I to judge, before accepting.

Comment: Let me modify my answer

Comment: Answer modified.

Comment: Now your last line, if it were true, would work for any (not just prime) number $p$. However its first equality has no reason to be true with your assumptions (or rather, the second and third expression are not even well-defined). What if I define $R$ as the standard $(\mathbf N_0, +)$ but with $a \times b := 0$ if $1 \notin \lbrace a,b \rbrace$? Then that's an object in your category, but there's no morphism from the standard $\mathbf N_0$ to this. I think you need more assumptions on $\times$ (like associativity) and the interplay of $+$ and $\times$ (like distributivity).

Comment: $\varphi(p) = \varphi\left(\sum_{i=1}^p 1\right) = \sum_{i=1}^p \varphi(1) = \sum_{i=1}^p 1_R$ and we would like it to be equal to $p \times 1_r$ so we can add the axiom $n \times  1_R = \sum_{i=1}^n 1_R$ for all $n\in\mathbf{N}_0$.

Comment: We cannot, because a priori $n \in \mathbf N_0$ is not even an element of $R$, so "$n \times 1_R$" makes no sense. What you get for free is that *if there is* a morphism $\varphi$, then it is necessarily unique, because $\varphi(n)$ must be $\sum_1^n 1_R$. But withourt further refinements of your category's objects, such a morphism $\varphi$ need not exist. My above counterexample still holds, as your proposed extra axiom does not work. What you need are axioms which make the above candidate a morphism. E.g. you need $(1_R + 1_R) \times (1_R +1_R) = 1_R+1_R+1_R+1_R$. As I said, distributivity.

Comment: This answer is still wrong. We can agree that the image of $\mathbf N$ under $\varphi_R$ will be all $\sum_1^n 1_R$, but that means that for such $\varphi_R$ to exist as morphism, we *need* associativity and distributivity on these elements because that's what their preimages satisfy. So the bare minimum of extra axiom that you need for all objects in the category, even if you don't want associativity and distributivity on *all* elements, is $(\sum_1^n 1_R) \times (\sum_1^m 1_R) = (\sum_1^{mn} 1_R)$ for all $m,n$. In which case one sees that one just copies a definition of natural numbers.

Answer (score 1):

OK, let's start with the observation by Max in the comments: The positive integers under multiplication are just the (unique up to isomorphism) free abelian monoid generated by the countably infinite set (“abelian” is just another word for “commutative” which is more commonly used in that context).

As long as you don't add more structure, that's all you can say. But before adding more structure, let's have a closer look at the structure that already is present. And that structure is given by the relation “divides”.

We have by definition that $a$ divides $b$ (written $a\mid b$) if there exists a $c$ such that $ac=b$. Another way to say the same is that $b$ is a multiple of $a$. Note that this is a structure that we get “for free” with the free abelian monoid.

Now looking at the relation $a\mid b$, we see that it is a partial order: It is reflexive ($a\mid a$), transitive (if $a\mid b$ and $b\mid c$, then $a\mid c$) and antisymmetric (if $a\mid b$ and $b\mid a$, then $a=b$).

Moreover, if we look at subsets that are totally ordered by that relation, we see that the largest such subsets are ordered just like the natural numbers (this is known as order type $\omega$).

So given that we have such a partial order, one may ask: Can we extend that to a total order? Maybe even of type $\omega$ again?

Indeed, we want to go even a bit further: The order type $\omega$ is a well order, that means every non-empty set has a smallest element, and as corrolary if an element is not the largest of the set, there is a next-larger element of that set.

And that allows us to demand a sort of uniformity for our order: Given any element $a$ other than $1$, the set of multiples of $a$ shall have the following property: The number of elements strictly between any multiple of $a$ and the next one shall be equal to the number of elements preceding $a$.

So if we denote our free abelian monoid with $P$ and that new order with $\le$, we have two conditions:

- Compatibility with the division order: $a\mid b \implies a\le b$.
- Uniformity: If $a>1$, $M_a = \{x\in P: a|x\}$, $b\in M_a$ and $c = \min\{x\in M_a: x>b\}$, then $\lvert \{x\in P: x < a\}\rvert = \lvert \{x\in P: b < x < c\}\rvert$. Here $\min$ is to be understood according to the order $\le$.

Let's see how this works out:

First, we have $1|a$ for all $a$, therefore $1\le a$ for all $a$, that is, $1$ has to be the smallest element.

So what about the next element, the one that comes after $1$? Let's call it $2$ (because, well, it's what comes after $1$).

Clearly, $2$ has to be a generator, because if it were not a generator, there would be an element $x\ne 1,2$ with $1\mid x$ and $x\mid 2$, and therefore $1<x<2$, in contradiction that $2$ is, by definition, the next element after $1$.  Or in other words, we have just proved that $2$ is prime.

Now thanks to uniformity, we know that the next element after $2$, let's call it $3$, is *not* a multiple of $2$ (because there's exactly one element, $1$, before $2$, there must be one element between $2$ and the next multiple of $2$. Thus $3$ is not a multiple of $2$. Since the only other element below $3$ is $1$, we again have that $3$ has to be a generator. In other words, we've just identified $3$ as the second prime.

Now let's look at the next element after $3$, which we name $4$. This one is, again, a multiple of $2$ (because there's exactly one element, namely $3$, strictly between it and the previous multiple of $2$, namely $2$ itself), but it is not a multiple of $3$. Since larger elements cannot divide it (the compatibility requirement), we know that the complete list of its divisors is $1$, $2$ and $4$ itself. But that is only possible if $4=2^2$.

Well, at that point it should be clear that this imposed order indeed forces the free abelian monoid to be identified with the positive integers. I'm not going to prove it, though.

Comment: Can you maybe state clearly what the statement is you are proving? Is it "if $M$ is a free abelian monoid on the countable infinite set, on which there is an order relation satisfying ..., then there is a unique isomorphism from $M$ to $(\mathbb N_+, \cdot)$ which identifies the order relation with the usual divisibility relation"?

Comment: It'll take me a while to digest this, but it's initially surprising that addition doesn't figure in it. It seems to appear within "uniformity".

Comment: Actually I think addition appears the moment you say "well order" and zero is identified appears once you say "total".

Comment: It looks like uniformity is a property that follows from the set being closed under both addition and multiplication, and multiplication distributing over addition.

Comment: If Goldbach's conjecture is true then this concept of uniformity should give rise to a strategy for proving it.  It might be worth re-reading your answer with the following in mind: Something in here implies Goldbach's conjecture.